# phonegap 3.4: bug with event online / offline

Tags: cordova

In phonegap when the event online product I trigger a reload of data but the problem is that the online or offline event fires two times in succession: it is creating a bug!

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener ("deviceready" onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener ("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener ("offline", onOffline, false);
```

Could you help me

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would only add `online` and `offline` event listeners after the device is ready:

```
document.addEventListener ("deviceready" onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener ("online", onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener ("offline", onOffline, false);
}


function onOnline(){
}

function onOffline(){
}
```

Comment: Waiting for deviceReady and updating Cordova to 3.6.3 fixed the issue. My apologies for my previous comment

Comment: Anyways, switching from CONNECTION_TYPE "wifi" to "4g" triggers the online event several times, is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try by  add plugin in this way:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

For further [details refer this link.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md)